# Slow Internet in 16.04 only in native apps

Tags: internet

I am using chrome and ubuntu and firefox and other application in ubuntu 16.04, only in dropbox, firefox and ubuntu software and update applications, internet runs very very slowly, while at the same time, in chrome it runs at blazing speeds, what is happening ?

Comment: For firefox try this: go to `about:config` (enter it where you type the url), search for `ipv6` and change` network.dns.disableIPv6` to `true`. See if that helps...